# Manipulating $2\sqrt{n} \sqrt{n+1} + 1 <2(n+1)$ so that its truth (for $n\geq0$) is more obvious

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following expression:
$$2\sqrt{n} \sqrt{n+1} + 1 <2(n+1)$$
Mapping this inequality out in Desmos, it shows that it holds for $n \geq 0$, but by visually examining it, it's difficult to say. Is there a way that this expression can be manipulated to be much more explicit and obvious that it holds true?

Comment: Note that $n\geq 0$. Move the $1$ to the right, $0\leq 2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}\lt 2n+3$, and square both sides: $4n(n+1) \lt 4n^2+12n+9$. Now do the operations and cancel.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin When you say "move 1 to the right", you mean subtract 1 on both sides of the inequality. How did you end up with $2n + 3$ on the right side?

Comment: Should have been $2n+1$: $2(n+1)-1 = 2n+2-1 = 2n+1$. Squaring gives $4n(n+1)\lt 4n^2+4n+1$, and this will be even clearer. Sorry for the mental arithmetical sign error.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Alright makes sense, thanks anyways.

Comment: @Robot416 Similar idea, write it as $\,\sqrt{4n(n+1)}=\sqrt{(2n+1)^2-1}\lt 2n+1\,$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\text{Given }\quad 2\sqrt{n} \sqrt{n+1} + 1 &<2(n+1) \quad n\ge0  
\\
\text{we subtract $1$ from both sides} &\text{ and square}\\ 
\big(2\sqrt{n} \sqrt{n+1}\big)^2 
&<\big(2(n+1) -1\big)^2 
\\
\text{below the inequality is easy to "see"}\\
4 n^2 + 4 n &< 4 n^2 + 4 n + 1
\\ \\
\text{Therefore, given $n\ge0,$ }\quad 2\sqrt{n} \sqrt{n+1} + 1 &<2(n+1)
\end{align*}

Comment: For the record, this does not prove the inequality, though it’s helpful scratch work to base a proof on. What you wrote here only shows that the inequality implies that $0 < 1$. Lots of things (well, everything that is true or false) imply that $0 < 1$.

Comment: @SteveKass Yeah, it's just one of the steps in my proof that I got stuck on, I managed to relate the expression on the left to an assumption I made, and I wanted to show that it could be bounded by the results I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

$2(n+1)>2\sqrt{n} \sqrt{n+1}+1\\
\iff
2n+1>2\sqrt{n} \sqrt{n+1}\\
\iff
n+\frac12>\sqrt{n} \sqrt{n+1}\\
\iff
n^2+n+\frac14>n(n+1)\\
$

which is true.